# Calls to BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync doesn't work after the windows 10 creators update

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wrote a code to connect to my bluetoothLE device. It was working fine before the windows 10 creators build update. After the update, when the program reaches the line of code bellow:

```
bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(bleDevice.Id);
```

It stays on that line forever. I've seen some workarounds for this problems but just for UWP projects. Any idea in how could I solve this problem?

Comment: I have this problem too. You are not alone.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case an exception was being thrown which made it look like this call was failing, but it was actually a different BTLE API.

Is your `bleDevice` object cached from somewhere? We had a probelm that ASQ strings were not working anymore and we had to get all devices known to the machine and filter them in a more general way.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk&prof=required) I found out a solution. While Microsoft doesn't fix the broken API, the easiest way to make the code work is add an AppID on windows registry. Here the steps to solve the problem:

1. Open regedit (type regedit.exe on search bar);
2. On Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppId add a new key (right click "new>key") with the name of your executable for your client process (for example, "YourClient.exe");
3. Right click on the right of the regedit window, then "new">"string value". After that, edit the "Name" property to be "AppID". Then, change the "Data" value to your program Id;
4. Add a new key on registry, similarly with the step 2, but with the Id of your executable;
5. Right click on the right of the regedit window, then "new">"DWORD value". Change the "Name" property to "AuthenticationLevel". Then change the "Data" value to 1.